# Merge tag [visual-studios-2015] into [visual-studio-2015]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[visual-studios-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studios-2015) was created several hours ago and has only a single [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studios-2015). This appears to be a typo of the more popular and applicable tag [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015). Should [visual-studios-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studios-2015) be deleted and merged into [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the question and change the tag. (I would, but you've got over 2k rep, so you can do it without needing reviewers to accept it).

Tags without questions attached to them [will be deleted at 3:00 AM UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/317795), which is in about an hour from now ;)